# Calculating operator (matrix) norms using eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, operator-theory

A remark that went unproven in class. 
It was said that the operator norm of a real linear transformation (real matrix) is the square root of the abs value of the max eigenvalue of $A^T*A$ (or maybe $A*A^T$?).

If $A$ is symmetric (and therefore orthonormally diagonalizable) everything is straightforward...

But the same calculation for $A^T*A$ only yields the norm of $A^T*A$....
So I want to prove the following lemmas, but they might not be true:

**1. The norm of $A$ equals the norm of its transpose.**

**2. Multiplicative property of the norm when restricting to $A^T*A$**

Are any of these true, and why?

If not, how can I prove the original claim?

Comment: $*$ means matrix multiplication? Usually we don't add $*$.

Comment: yes, matrix mult'.

Comment: Consider bilinear form $x,y\mapsto (Ax,y)$ where $(u,v)=\sum_ju_jv_j$. Show that $\lVert A\rVert=\sup_{\lVert x\rVert,\lVert y\rVert\le1}\lvert(Ax,y)\rvert$. Note that $(Ax,y)=(A,A^Ty)$, and conclude that $\lVert A\rVert=\lVert A^T\rVert$. Now we have $\lVert A^TA\rVert\le\lVert A\rVert^2$. For the opposite inequality, just recall the definition that $\lVert A\rVert^2=\sup_{\lVert x\rVert\le1}(Ax,Ax)=\sup_{\lVert x\rVert\le1}(x,A^TAx)$.

Comment: Another proof by polar decomposition (which should be left as an exercise) is also instructive: suppose first that $A$ is invertible, then $A^TA$ is positive definite, then there exists positive definite $B$ such that $A^TA=B^2$. hence $A=OB$ for some orthogonal matrix $O$, which holds even if $A$ isn't invertible. Now $\lVert A^TA\rVert=\lVert B\rVert^2=\lVert A\rVert^2$. Most steps aren't that direct for beginners, hence are exercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact you need is that, for the operator norm, $\|AB\|\leq\|A\|\,\|B\|$. With this,:
\begin{align}
\|A\|^2&=\sup\{\|Ax\|^2:\ \|x\|=1\}=\sup\{(Ax)^TAx:\ \|x\|=1\}
=\sup\{x^TA^TAx:\ \|x\|=1\}\\
&\leq\sup\{\|A^TAx\|\,\|x\|:\ \|x\|=1\}=\sup\{\|A^TAx\|:\ \|x\|=1\}\\
&\leq\|A^TA\|,
\end{align}
where the first inequality is Cauchy-Schwarz and the second one is just by definition of the supremum norm.

Then
$$
\|A\|^2\leq\|A^TA\|\leq\|A^T\|\,\|A\|,
$$
from where we obtain $\|A^T\|\leq\|A\|$. But we can apply this last inequality to $A^T$, and so $\|A^T\|=\|A\|$, and $\|A\|^2=\|A^TA\|$.

Answer (score 0):

1. The norm you talking about is a matrix $L_2$ norm  which is defined as following
   $$\|A\|_2=\sqrt{\max_n\lambda_n(AA^t)}
   $$
   where $\lambda_n(B)$ is a n'th eigenvalue of matrix $B$.

This norm is induced from a vector $L_2$ norm given by 
$$\|v\|_2=\sqrt{\sum_i |v_i|^2}$$

2. A matrix norm induced from a vector norm is defined by
   $$\|A\|=\max_{v}\frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|}$$
   however this is not the only way to get matrix norm (there are norms which aren't induced from a vector norm, e.g. Frobineous norm).
3. The property $\|A\|=\|A^T\|$ is not always true, for example for
   $L_1$ and $L_\infty$ for matrices the following is true
   $\|A\|_1=\|A^T\|_\infty$
4. For a quadratic matrices we have $\|AB\|\le \|A\|\|B\|$